# How to load script inside div dynamically from json

Tags: jquery, json

I have a service at the backend which return the script and I want to inject dynamcailly inside the div. I use the below approach

```
 $.get("/api/service/getdata", function (data) {


           $("#searchBox1").append(data.script);
       });
```

But it is not executing inside a div. The above simply put the script inside the div. How can I execute the script?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ . Jquery provides a way of dynamically loading script files via ajax and executing it.

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think more information may be needed here. If the results of the AJAX call returns something like the following:

```
<script>var cool = function () { alert('You\'re Cool!'); }</script>
```

Then you would need to either call `cool()` after the script has been appended or append a dynamically generated script tag to do it.

```
<script>cool()</script>
```

If more than a function is returned, we will need to see a better example.

Comment: Unfortunately it is more than a function return. The search box suppose to be created when script render. Any suggestion how can I execute the script?

Comment: I am going to need to see what the script looks like, even a snippet of it would be helpful.

Comment: if (typeof (HCSB) == 'undefined') { HCSB = { _options: [], _scriptLoaded: false, _domLoaded: false, _domLoadInit: false, _sbExternalConfiguration: {}, loadCSS: function (id, href, appendOrInsertBefore) { appendOrInsertBefore = (typeof appendOrInsertBefore === "undefined") ? ..

Comment: That's very complex. Not sure whether the above snippet would be helpful for you?

Comment: So it looks like it wants to return an `HCSB` object. So, after you append the script inside the div, you need to initialize that object. `HCSB.init();` or `new HSCB()`. I don't know what is needed exaclty as you only posted a snippet. :)

Comment: Alright, so looking at that link, you will want to call `HCSB.buildSB()` and pass some options to it. Looks like it accepts 3 arguments.

Comment: Actually the problem is the searchbox appear on the head tag when the above script execute which I showed in the question. I want to execute inside the div. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, why do you want it to execute inside the div? If you want the script to update some html element, can't you just pass it a reference to the element you want it to modify?

Comment: I want to execute inside the div because I want to display the search box as I told above that it will become the search box after the script rendered.

Comment: @user2866746 as long as the reference to the div is passed on to the script, why does it matter where the script is defined? Just modify the script a little bit to write to a specific element. Alternatively, you could try to hook into the on render event of the div (not sure if such an event exists) and try to execute your script as part of that event...

Comment: Finally I came up with the solution using postscribe https://github.com/krux/postscribe

Comment: But I have two scripts to render on the same page. The above solution works only for one script, however it does not load the second one. Any idea?